# Angular2 *ngIf with child directive

Tags: angular, directive, angular-ng-if

I can't seem to get my directive to work and wonder if it is due to the use of an *ngif.

**Component HTML:**

```
<div *ngIf="ticket" class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h4 appUsername>{{ticket.raisedBy.firstName}} {{ticket.raisedBy.surname}}</h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

 @Directive({
  selector: '[appUsername]'
 })

 export class UsernameDirective {constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    console.log('App Username directive init');
    el.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
 }
}
```

The *ngIf is required in the component HTML as I am collecting data from a JSON service on ngOnInit.

*Code ignored for brevity*: I am adding the directive to a "shared" module which exports the Directive. This module is then imported in to the main app module.

Is this a known problem or is it my code ?

**Update** I got this working now however I am having to import the directive in to the module which contains the component. Can I not import it in to the AppModule and then use is globally ?

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected behavior? Have you tried to move your `red` code to `ngAfterViewInit()`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The Directive is not changing the colour of the text in the h4 within the component HTML. Nor firing the console.log

Comment: Did you import the shared module to the module that contains above component?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The imports all work and there are no coding errors within the console of the application.

Comment: If the constructor is not executed it's almost 100% a problem with module configuration. The selector matches, there is not much else that could cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Angular` module system works like this:

- You need to `declare` a `Component`/`Directive`/... in exactly ONE `NgModule`.
  You can then use it in the `Component`s that are part of this `NgModule`.
- To use a `Component`/`Directive`/... in any other `NgModule`, you need to `export` it in from the declaring `NgModule` and `import` the declaring `NgModule` in the `NgModule` where you want to use it.

In your case you `declare` and `export` the `Directive` in the `SharedModule` and `import` the `SharedModule` in the `AppModule`, but you use the `Directive` in another `NgModule`, which does not `import` `SharedModule` and does not `import` `AppModule` and therefore does not know your `Directive`.

So to use something in a `NgModule`, it needs to `declare` it, `import` the declaring `NgModule` or `import` a `NgModule`, which `import`s the declaring `NgModule`.
Importing only works if the declaring `NgModule` exports the `Directive`.